# requests_html returns black

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests-html

```
    Python 3.8.2 (default, Apr  8 2020, 14:31:25) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from requests_html import HTMLSession
>>> session = HTMLSession()
>>> r = session.get('https://www.sahibinden.com/ilan/emlak-konut-gunluk-kiralik-holiday-business-suit-lux-otel-konforunda-suit-daireler-803346031/detay')
>>> r.html.find("#classifiedId")
[]
```

I ran this code but the output is empty. I tried `r.html.render()` but result didn't change. I also tried finding it with xpath but still no result. How can I fix that?

Comment: It seems to me, there is no elements with id=classifiedId in the source of the webpage.

Comment: What information are you trying to get? only `Classified Id`?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/sIuaCqO.png @Dmitry You should however check again through python code. Get the raw content. They may be sending less information when e.g. using a generic user agent.

Comment: @TinNguyen you should login to this website firstly. This webpage can't be opened without login. You can make this steps programmatically with Python.

Comment: There is an element with that id. I'm trying to get a list on the right. User agent is Chrome. It doesn't require login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The site needs that you specify `User-Agent` and a cookie named `"s3IssGuY1"`. If this cookie needs to be changed over time (and when) I don't know, but you can change it accordingly (from Firefox/Chrome developer tools):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:77.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/77.0'}
url = 'https://www.sahibinden.com/ilan/emlak-konut-gunluk-kiralik-holiday-business-suit-lux-otel-konforunda-suit-daireler-803346031/detay'
cookies = {'s3IssGuY1': 'A_Lne-ByAQAAWJ_crjFYgFyVj0loVQQA3jwlYwVTH-vnpfLSbIkEJkwRS9NDAVX4a-mcuNvjwH8AADQwAAAAAA=='}
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers, cookies=cookies).content, 'html.parser')

for st, sp in zip(soup.select('.classifiedInfoList strong'), soup.select('.classifiedInfoList span')):
    print('{:<30} {}'.format(st.get_text(strip=True), sp.get_text(strip=True)))
```

Prints:

```
İlan No                        803346031
İlan Tarihi                    23 Haziran 2020
Emlak Tipi                     Günlük Kiralık Daire
m² (Brüt)                      35
m² (Net)                       30
Oda Sayısı                     Stüdyo (1+0)
Bulunduğu Kat                  5
Kat Sayısı                     5
Isıtma                         Merkezi
Banyo Sayısı                   1
Site İçerisinde                Hayır
Kimden                         Emlak Ofisinden
```

Comment: Ididn't understand the last line. Can you explain?

Comment: @enes3626 The last line `print()` just prints [formatted string](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/string.html#format-examples): first value is left aligned fixed with string (30 characters)

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your help. You're a life savior.

Answer (score 0):

If the browser does not require you to open or not, you can use selenium to open your system browser and be able to access the element directly.

first:

you need to install chrome or firefox driver

second:

need to install selenium in your python with pip

third:

in your texteditor or ide write these code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

driver = webdriver.FireFox(executable_path="your driver path in your pc or laptop")
driver.get("your url")

sleep(10)

elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("use xpath here")

print(elem.text)

driver.close()
```

Comment: I know selenium but it's so slow.

Comment: So you need to use the network section in your browser to find a suitable request according to the response.

Comment: and i think this page load with javascript so you need to use way i said